# Javascript classList.toggle not removing class

Tags: javascript, tabs, accordion, responsive

I'm trying to toggle the class "open" so that my accordion would close when clicking on the same button. They close fine when clicking on another button but not when clicking on itself. This needs to be done in Javascript and not jQuery. Please view in mobile as that is where the issue is:

Here is my JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/pwouns7o/1/

And here is my Javascript code:

```
var accordion = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var panel = document.getElementsByClassName("panel");

for(var i = 0; i < accordion.length; i++){
  accordion[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    removeOpen();
    // add active class to clicked element and open class to next slibling
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('open');
    this.classList.toggle('active');
  });
};

function removeOpen (){
 // remove open class for all elements
    for(var i = 0; i < panel.length; i++) {
       panel[i].classList.remove('open');
    }
};
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: *'classList.toggle not removing class... I'm trying to toggle the class "open"'* The only place you're using `classList.toggle` is with the class `"active"`, not `"open"`.

Comment: thanks my bad, I have updated the code preview with the toggle on open with the same results

Comment: _not sure what I'm doing wrong, as the_ ... don't keep everyone in suspense!

Comment: [**`var toggleResult = this.classList.toggle('active'); this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('open', toggleResult);`**](https://jsfiddle.net/mpansteo/).

Comment: Your update changes the code quite a lot. Now that you're using `.toggle` with the `"open"` class, every one that had been closed, will now be opened. That seems like a big step away from functioning code.

Comment: thank you ibrahim, this worked perfect!

Comment: Ibrahim - I just noticed there is a little problem with this still. Sometimes I have to click twice on a button for it to show up, any ideas what could cause that?